# desktop browsing in iOS 13 with WKWebView?

Tags: ios, wkwebview, ios13

According to WWDC 2019 video 203, I should be able to see desktop browsing in a full-screen WKWebView on an iPad. But I'm not seeing it. For example, when I go to google in my WKWebView, I'm clearly seeing the mobile version of the site.

I've tried everything the video suggests. I've set the `applicationNameForUserAgent`, and the web inspector shows that it is being set as they advise in the video:

```
"5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.0 MyBrowser/1.0"
```

I've also implemented the navigation delegate to request `.desktop` mode:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, preferences: WKWebpagePreferences, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy, WKWebpagePreferences) -> Void) {
    preferences.preferredContentMode = .desktop
    print("asking for desktop version")
    decisionHandler(.allow, preferences)
}
```

That method is being called. But I'm still seeing the mobile version of the site.

When I go to the same site in Safari on the same iPad, or if I use an SFSafariViewController, I do see the desktop version of the site, as advertised. How can I get that version of the site in my WKWebView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by using `"Version/13.0.1 Safari/605.1.15"` as my `applicationNameForUserAgent` string.

(Where did I get that string? Basically I simply stole it from the SFSafariViewController.)

This seems like a bug. Apple's video implies that I should *not* have to lie about who the user agent is in order to get desktop browsing.

Comment: this saved me. Any word on current state? Meaning, is this issue solved? @matt

Answer (score 1):

I'm disappointed at this bug of WKWebView on iPadOS (iPad iOS13).

This is the code that get each version programmatically, generates a string in the format indicated by @matt, and adds it to user agent.

```swift
let systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
let webkitVersion = (Bundle(for: SFSafariViewController.self).object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") as? String) ?? "605.1.5"
webConfig.applicationNameForUserAgent = "Version/\(systemVersion) Safari/\(webkitVersion)"
```